# Laravel 5.7 Driver [] is not supported

Tags: php, laravel, ftp

Laravel version: 5.7

```
//filesystem.php

return [
    'default' => 'local',

    'cloud' => 's3',

    'disks' => [
//        ....
        'ftp' => [
            "driver" => env("ftp"),
            "host" => env("FTP_SERVER"),
            "username" => env("FTP_USER"),
            "password" => env("FTP_PASSWORD")
        ],
    ],

];
```

```
//Controller
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

public function test(){
    dd(Storage::disk("ftp"));

}
```

But return error `Driver [] is not suppoted`

Tried to use commands to clear cache and cofig

```
php artisan config:clear

php artisan cache:clear
```

Also installed `league/flysystem-sftp ~1.0` I think it is not neccesary, and clear cache and config after install, but same. If I use local it works.

Answer (score 1):

It should be `"driver" => "ftp"` – i.e. no `env`.

*(unless you really intended to have the `ftp` variable set, but failed to do so).*